# R non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot, factors

I want to plot the boxplot of a dataset but I get the following error.

```
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I import the data as follows:

```
raw.data <- read.table("./GDS4879.clean", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

I remove the first two columns:

```
data <- raw.data[,-c(1,2)]
```

And finally i try to plot the boxplot:

```
boxplot(data)
```

I have previously used the same code for another dataset (almost the same as this one) and works fine. Just before I plot the data I use the `class()` function and both datasets are dataframes but when I do `lapply(data, class)` in the first dataset I get that all columns are dataframes but in this case I get factors. Am I missing something ?

The dataset I use can be found here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser?acc=GDS4879
I use the Rstudio to perform the analysis.

Comment: `boxplot()` wants a numeric vector.  You've given it a data frame.  You could convert to a matrix and it should work, since a matrix is a vector with dimensions added.

Comment: works like a charm, could you explain why it works one the one case and not the other ? (i mean when i do not convert to a matrix)